# how come "take off" means impersonating or imitating?

Tags: etymology

I looked up Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, it says that one of meanings of "take off" is *imitating or impersonating*? I cant figure out how does it come, I mean, take what off when someone do the imitation?

Comment: It is strange, isn't it? I've used it all my life and I don't have any idea where it came from, either.

Comment: take-off, "caricature," colloquial, 1846, from earlier sense of "thing that detracts from something, drawback" (1826), from take (v.) + off (adv.). [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/takeoff)

Comment: When we take someone off, we don't just attempt to exactly imitate them; we exaggerate things, e.g. accent, mannerisms, etc. The object is to get a laugh at the expense of the person being taken off.

Comment: maybe it's connected to 'take' in the sense of opinion, assessment, approach, treatment. "What's your take on the candidate?" "a new take on an old idea" https://www.dictionary.com/browse/take  definitions 100, 101

Comment: I'm not sure this is all that frequent in AmE...

Comment: It's frequently used for amateur vocal impersonations. _He did a terrific takeoff on `Celebrity`_ means he imitated the celebrity's voice and mannerisms, usually in a comedic way.

Comment: @Cascabel Common, in my experience. Frequent in comedy—a take-off or a riff on a public figure. *Riff* from music—variations on a theme, perhaps impromptu.